# how can I copy part of the string after the token

Tags: c, string, copy, token

how can I copy part of the string after the token

I have this input

Microsoft Corporation;   NASDAQ MSFT    259.94B

how can I copy part of string that begin from NASDAQ to the end of the string, the token here would be the semicolon

would something like this work?

```
strcpy(tempString, strtok(buffer, ";")+4)
```

Comment: You can always run your code and test it.

Comment: yeah I ran the code after I post this question `strcpy(tempString, strtok(buffer, ";")+4)` won't work, how should I copy part of the string?

Comment: @bluebk Define "won't work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Something like*** your code would work. I don't understand the `+ 4`, though, as far as I'm concerned, it should be `+ 2`. Also, don't use `strtok()` for finding a character in a string - use `strchr()` for that, it's more lightweight and it doesn't require the base string to be modifiable.

So,

```
strcpy(tempString, strchr(buffer, ';') + 2);
```

or the safer

```
snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%s", strchr(buffer, ';') + 2);
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank, I forgot strchr since using strtok modify the string that make it reading the wrong data

Comment: @Jim It's even worse than `strcpy()`. If we are being safety freaks (and why wouldn't we), then `snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%s", strchr())` is the proper solution.

Comment: There's a downside to safety freakdom.

Comment: @Jim Namely? People won't be able to buffer-overflow your programz? Or wat?

Comment: It just makes everything more complicated and slower.  I'm just saying if a small program is written that will never take more than a 100 character line of data, then you MIGHT not need to bounds check if you have an ample buffer to receive it.

Comment: @Jim Euh, yes. Then, why were ***you*** being pedantic about `strcpy()`?

Comment: @Jim Also, as to "slower": please **no more premature optimization today,** kthxbye.

Comment: @H2CO3 most of design patterns is premature optimization.

Comment: @Jim I know you meant that the code would be slower. And I meant "who cares it if it's slower?".

Comment: @Jim No, design patterns are not relevant.